# Cartesian Product Bijection?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJVOs.jpg

This is what was posted. Can anybody help me understand why the function is defined to be f(i,j) = n(i-1)+j and not ij? I must be confused on what it's asking or cartesian products in general. There really isn't too much information on cartesian products in my book. Any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry to ask but how does that explain that the function is defined to be n(i-1)+j

Comment: The Cartesian product $A\times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs: $\{(a, b)\mid (a \in A, b\in B)\}$.  So, if we use $A = \{1, 2\}, B =\{2, 3\}$, then $A\times B = \{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)\}$

Comment: I was not given f(i,j) = n(i-1)+j. I had to construct it and I don't understand the process behind it. Everything written is just the solution to the question.

Comment: Your function takes an ordered pair $(i, j)\in A\times B,$ where $i$ is an arbitrary element of $A$, and $j$ is an arbitrary element of $B$, with $f(i, j= n(i-1) +j$ to then out put a natural number in your set.  The problem is, your function is a function of three variables, since you've given no indication of what is meant by $n$.

Comment: I understand how to prove that f(n,i) = n(i-1) + j is bijective but i don't understand how to GET/CONSTRUCT that function (because it was again not given).

Comment: By the construction of a bijection $A\times B\to\{1,2,\dots,mn\}$ it is quite "natural" here to think in the line of: $(1,1)\mapsto1$, $(1,2)\mapsto 2$,...,$(1,n)\mapsto n$, $(2,1)\mapsto n+1$ et cetera, ending up with $(m,n)\mapsto mn$.

Comment: No, our teacher posted the solution to the question but it still doesn't make sense to me. I can't ask him because he's out of town and busy.

Comment: Then I'm giving you the benefit of any doubt.

Comment: Ok. May i ask again how to construct it? We never had homework questions like this before so I'm pretty confused on it.

Comment: @someonewashere do you agree that $(1,1)\mapsto1$ is a natural way to start?

Comment: @drhab: Yes that is a good place to start.

Comment: Well, go on as I described in my former comment.

Comment: Since i is in {1,....,m} and j is in {1,....n}, the set of ordered pairs will contain (1,1),...., (1,n),.....,(m,1),.....,(m,n) and they map to 1,n,m, and mn respectively.  Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Without using the defined function the teacher gave, why would you say that (2,1) maps to n+1 and not just 2*1 = 2?

Comment: If you choose for $(i,j)\mapsto i\times j$ then the function in not injective (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it for e.g. $m=3$ and $n=4$

Constructing a **bijection** $\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \times\left\{ 1,2,3,4\right\} \to\left\{ 1,2,\dots,11,12\right\} $
comes to the same as filling in the blanks in table:

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{array}$

With numbers $1,2,\dots,12$.

A very natural way to do that is:

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
3 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}$

If we search for a prescription of $f$ then we find: $$f\left(i,j\right)=4\left(i-1\right)+j$$

Comment: Ah, I think this is starting to make more sense now. Thank you so much. I'll take a look at this more in-depth after classes. If I have any more questions, can I continue to ask you? You explain it well.